# При переходе на таск крашится канбан доска на реакте

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При переходе на таск должно открываться его описание.
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

```js
    <Routes>
    <Route exact path={'/'} element = { <Board {...props} />}/>
    <Route path={'/tasks/:taskId'} element = { <TaskDetail {...props}/>}/>      
    </Routes>
    <Link key={task.title} to={`/tasks/${task.id}`}>
    <div className={btnGroupClasses}>{task.title}</div>
    </Link>
```

Comment: Приведите [mcve], этот огрызок кода никакой полезной информации не несёт

Comment: судя по стектрейсу ошибка не в маршрутах в списке задач, а уже внутри TaskDetail. и возникает внутри хука useMatch, которому был передан пустой аргумент. а вобще, если бы приложение было запущено в дебаге, то подсветилась бы строчка с ошибкой, а так можно только примерно гадать где она